# Export feature classes with ArcGIS Pro attribute rules to FGDB that can be opened in ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-pro, compatibility, attribute-rules

I have data stored in an enterprise database that our team is currently editing using ArcGIS Pro. Attribute rules are set up on some of the feature classes in order to auto-increment IDs as new features are created. The problem is that implementing attribute rules in ArcGIS Pro makes a feature class unreadable by ArcMap or ArcCatalog, and our client hasn't yet transitioned from ArcMap to ArcGIS Pro. How can I export this data in a way that our client can use it, while also preserving all of the domains? In the past I have exported from ArcGIS Pro to geopackage format, which can then be opened in ArcMap, but for this I would then need to export the geopackage back to FGDB in ArcMap and then re-add the domains back in. I am looking for a simpler workflow since I will need to do this every month.

Comment: Have you tried making a copy of the FGDB and then running `Delete Attribue Rule` to remove all the rules on the copy? (I have never tried it, so interested myself in whether it works).

Comment: @bixb0012 This worked! Thank you. I deleted the attribute rules from both the feature classes that had them, and now I can view the data in ArcCatalog with no error messages.